# Massive power usage for a simple VHDL design

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I'm trying to implement Gaussian elimination to calculate Matrix rank, The following code uses lots of power like 60 watts for `2x2` matrix which looks weird considering it uses `3%` of DSPs too. If no division used the power consumption become as low as 10 watts but still massive for a `2x2` matrix.

```vhdl
myloop2 : for k in 0 to matrix_RowClmsize-1 loop
            M(op_i,k) <= M(op_i,k) - ((M(op_i,op_j) * M(op_j,k)) / M(op_j,op_j));
end loop myloop2;
```

Obviously `M` is the matrix.

I'm using ZedBoard and Vivado 2017.2

[image: power summary]
[image: percentage]
[image: post implementation]
[image: using power optimization]

**Edit:**

[image]

Comment: what frequency do you have the estimator set to?

Comment: @JonRB I don't know, How could I change/read the frequency?

Comment: that should be part of the constraints when it is synthesised. if no clk is specified it will attempt to use the maximum the chip will support. You may or may not get timing violations. You should be setting the constraint clock a bit faster (5-10%) than the part you have. This gives you a bit of margin in closing timing violations before having to refactor you code.

Comment: I'm just trying to generate an IP out of it so I'd let everything on default. (The max for the board is 866MHZ)

Comment: "just" love that word :) there is a very high chance it will try to use 866MHz unless you have told the toolchain what frequency it should use. Also you have 25% IO utilisation, while this should be due to a UCF associated with this board, are you sure there are no other IP blocks being synthed at the same time?

Comment: I'm sure it's the only one, if you kindly check the edit.

Comment: @JonRB, the synthesis tool (Vivado here) will not target the highest clock frequency the chip can do if none is specified. Unless guided otherwise, it will produce a design that somewhat balances frequency of operation against gate usage, then report the max. frequency that resultant design can do. You have to work hard with constraints and tool settings to make it target the highest possible frequency the chip can do and to use excessive gates to get there.

Comment: @TonyM Where should I find the final suggested/valid frequency reported? I'm suspect that if tool does that, why the power is still on the danger side?

Comment: You should be using PLL/MMCM in your whole setup. Check its output clock frequency and confirm if thats the clock freq you require